# How to use ffmpeg api to make a filter overlay water mark?

Tags: c, ffmpeg

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

FFmpeg : 4.4.0

Test video :

Input #0, hevc, from './videos/akiyo_352x288p25.265':
Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv), 352x288, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc

Test watermark:

200*200.png

I copy ffmpeg official example.

Compiler no error, run no error , but i can't see add watermark

Here is my code

```c
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersink.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersrc.h>
int open_input_file(AVFormatContext *fmt, AVCodecContext **codecctx, AVCodec *codec, const char *filename, int index)
{
    int ret = 0;
    char msg[500];
    *codecctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    ret = avcodec_parameters_to_context(*codecctx, fmt->streams[index]->codecpar);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        printf("avcodec_parameters_to_context error,ret:%d\n", ret);
        
        return -1;
    }

    // open 解码器
    ret = avcodec_open2(*codecctx, codec, NULL);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        printf("avcodec_open2 error,ret:%d\n", ret);
        
        return -2;
    }
    printf("pix:%d\n", (*codecctx)->pix_fmt);
    return ret;
}

int init_filter(AVFilterContext **buffersrc_ctx, AVFilterContext **buffersink_ctx, AVFilterGraph **filter_graph, AVStream *stream, AVCodecContext *codecctx, const char *filter_desc)
{
    int ret = -1;
    char args[512];
    char msg[500];
    const AVFilter *buffersrc = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");
    const AVFilter *buffersink = avfilter_get_by_name("buffersink");

    AVFilterInOut *input = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    AVFilterInOut *output = avfilter_inout_alloc();

    AVRational time_base = stream->time_base;
    enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmts[] = {AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, AV_PIX_FMT_NONE};

    if (!output || !input || !filter_graph)
    {
        ret = -1;
        printf("avfilter_graph_alloc/avfilter_inout_alloc error,ret:%d\n", ret);
        
        goto end;
    }
    snprintf(args, sizeof(args), "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d", codecctx->width, codecctx->height, codecctx->pix_fmt, stream->time_base.num, stream->time_base.den, codecctx->sample_aspect_ratio.num, codecctx->sample_aspect_ratio.den);
    ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(buffersrc_ctx, buffersrc, "in", args, NULL, *filter_graph);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        printf("avfilter_graph_create_filter buffersrc error,ret:%d\n", ret);
        
        goto end;
    }

    ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(buffersink_ctx, buffersink, "out", NULL, NULL, *filter_graph);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        printf("avfilter_graph_create_filter buffersink error,ret:%d\n", ret);
        
        goto end;
    }
    ret = av_opt_set_int_list(*buffersink_ctx, "pix_fmts", pix_fmts, AV_PIX_FMT_NONE, AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        printf("av_opt_set_int_list error,ret:%d\n", ret);
        
        goto end;
    }
    /*
 * The buffer source output must be connected to the input pad of
 * the first filter described by filters_descr; since the first
 * filter input label is not specified, it is set to "in" by
 * default.
 */
    output->name = av_strdup("in");
    output->filter_ctx = *buffersrc_ctx;
    output->pad_idx = 0;
    output->next = NULL;

    /*
 * The buffer sink input must be connected to the output pad of
 * the last filter described by filters_descr; since the last
 * filter output label is not specified, it is set to "out" by
 * default.
 */
    input->name = av_strdup("out");
    input->filter_ctx = *buffersink_ctx;
    input->pad_idx = 0;
    input->next = NULL;

    if ((ret = avfilter_graph_parse_ptr(*filter_graph, filter_desc, &input, &output, NULL)) < 0)
    {
        printf("avfilter_graph_parse_ptr error,ret:%d\n", ret);
        
        goto end;
    }

    if ((ret = avfilter_graph_config(*filter_graph, NULL)) < 0)
    {
        printf("avfilter_graph_config error,ret:%d\n", ret);
        
        goto end;
    }
    end:
    avfilter_inout_free(&input);
    avfilter_inout_free(&output);
    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ret;
    char msg[500];
    const char *filter_descr = "drawbox=x=100:y=100:w=100:h=100:color=pink@0.5"; // OK
    //const char *filter_descr = "movie=200.png[wm];[in][wm]overlay=10:10[out]"; //Test
    // const char *filter_descr = "scale=640:360,transpose=cclock";
    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
    AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx;
    AVFilterContext *buffersink_ctx;
    AVFilterContext *buffersrc_ctx;
    AVFilterGraph *filter_graph;
    AVCodec *codec;
    int video_stream_index = -1;

    AVPacket packet;
    AVFrame *pFrame;
    AVFrame *pFrame_out;
    filter_graph = avfilter_graph_alloc();
    FILE *fp_yuv = fopen("test.yuv", "wb+");
    ret = avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, argv[1], NULL, NULL);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        printf("avformat_open_input error,ret:%d\n", ret);
        
        return -1;
    }

    ret = avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        printf("avformat_find_stream_info error,ret:%d\n", ret);
        
        return -2;
    }

    ret = av_find_best_stream(pFormatCtx, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, &codec, 0);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        printf("av_find_best_stream error,ret:%d\n", ret);
        
        return -3;
    }
    // 获取到视频流索引
    video_stream_index = ret;

    av_dump_format(pFormatCtx, 0, argv[1], 0);
    if ((ret = open_input_file(pFormatCtx, &pCodecCtx, codec, argv[1], video_stream_index)) < 0)
    {
        ret = -1;
        printf("open_input_file error,ret:%d\n", ret);
        
        goto end;
    }

    if ((ret = init_filter(&buffersrc_ctx, &buffersink_ctx, &filter_graph, pFormatCtx->streams[video_stream_index], pCodecCtx, filter_descr)) < 0)
    {
        ret = -2;
        printf("init_filter error,ret:%d\n", ret);
        
        goto end;
    }
    pFrame = av_frame_alloc();
    pFrame_out = av_frame_alloc();
    while (1)
    {
        if ((ret = av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)) < 0)
            break;

        if (packet.stream_index == video_stream_index)
        {
            ret = avcodec_send_packet(pCodecCtx, &packet);
            if (ret < 0)
            {
                printf("avcodec_send_packet error,ret:%d\n", ret);
                
                break;
            }

            while (ret >= 0)
            {
                ret = avcodec_receive_frame(pCodecCtx, pFrame);
                if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if (ret < 0)
                {
                    printf("avcodec_receive_frame error,ret:%d\n", ret);
                    
                    goto end;
                }

                pFrame->pts = pFrame->best_effort_timestamp;

                /* push the decoded frame into the filtergraph */
                ret = av_buffersrc_add_frame_flags(buffersrc_ctx, pFrame, AV_BUFFERSRC_FLAG_KEEP_REF);
                if (ret < 0)
                {
                    printf("av_buffersrc_add_frame_flags error,ret:%d\n", ret);
                    
                    break;
                }

                /* pull filtered frames from the filtergraph */
                while (1)
                {
                    ret = av_buffersink_get_frame(buffersink_ctx, pFrame_out);
                    if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
                        break;
                    if (ret < 0)
                        goto end;
                    if (pFrame_out->format == AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P)
                    {
                        //Y, U, V
                        for (int i = 0; i < pFrame_out->height; i++)
                        {
                            fwrite(pFrame_out->data[0] + pFrame_out->linesize[0] * i, 1, pFrame_out->width, fp_yuv);
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < pFrame_out->height / 2; i++)
                        {
                            fwrite(pFrame_out->data[1] + pFrame_out->linesize[1] * i, 1, pFrame_out->width / 2, fp_yuv);
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < pFrame_out->height / 2; i++)
                        {
                            fwrite(pFrame_out->data[2] + pFrame_out->linesize[2] * i, 1, pFrame_out->width / 2, fp_yuv);
                        }
                    }
                    av_frame_unref(pFrame_out);
                }
                av_frame_unref(pFrame);
            }
        }
        av_packet_unref(&packet);
    }
    end:
    avcodec_free_context(&pCodecCtx);
    fclose(fp_yuv);
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the equivalent FFmpeg CLI command (Same operation using FFmpeg command line interface)?

Comment: `"drawbox=x=100:y=100:w=100:h=100:color=pink@0.5"` would not give you an overlay effect. As @Rotem says above, you need to put together a filtergraph that works with the cli `ffmpeg` then use it in place of this example? filtergraph description.

Comment: @Rotem ffmpeg -i ./videos/akiyo_352x288p25.265 -vf "movie=200.png[wm];[in][wm]overlay=30:10[out]" decoder_filter_output.yuv   when i use this ffmpeg cli it work well

Comment: @kesh I also test ```const char *filter_descr = "movie=200.png[wm];[in][wm]overlay=10:20[out]"; // Test``` in my code , this not work

Comment: When i use ```const char *filter_descr = "drawbox=x=100:y=100:w=100:h=100:color=pink@0.5"; // OK``` it work well

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep the same pts of the frame and the overlay, set the pFrame->pts = 0 may be work

Comment: Suggesting to try something that maybe works would make more sense as a comment on the question than as an answer.